# Running main class parameters

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using intelliJ and I ran the main method of my java class and here is what i got for an output

```
 usage: MyJavaClass
 -comment <arg>   comments for generated patch
 -force           force overwrite of merge conflicts.  Defaults to false.
 -patch <arg>     output file for generated patch
  -source <arg>    Source name (required)
 -target <arg>    Target name (required)
  -v               verbose output.  Defaults to false.
 -DCLIENT_CONF    Location for client configuration settings 

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I think I am supposed to enter 2 databases names(local) because I want to transfer information from the first to the second,but how do I pass arguments cause I get the screen above,thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the Run | Edit Configurations... menu item, find the configuration for `MyJavaClass` and specify the arguments in the "Program arguments" field.

Answer (score 0):

In Maven projects you could use the exec-maven-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.path.MyJavaClass</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-source</argument>
                    <argument>-target</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```